# How to clean up gibberish text in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way to clean up text in Power BI? I have an Excel Spreadsheet with almost Five Hundred Thousand rows and I have imported into Power BI. Is there a way in Power BI to cleanup a text like this in the screen shot below? I need to remove all those //, ***, ... and all other gibberish text etc. I did filter out those but there are almost five hundred thousand rows and Power Query doesn't load all and that option is not available. Is there any other way than filtering in Power Query?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no function for gibberish text. The hardest part is to define what is gibberish. You can create a calculate column in M language with multiple OR statement like in this example and filter True/False;

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCkpNL81JLApOzStJzUtOVYrViVbS19cH08GJOanFYYk5pRBhPT09MO2SWJKIImBoZGxgYglm+qVWlKCYFZBYlJhelJhmAua55qTkFyWm5IM5iSk56ZlpKenFGWCuhhXMcgiAWYEAYBH3/PwUsMMUFUA6YgE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [gibberishOrNot = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"gibberishOrNot", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Contains([gibberishOrNot],"//") or Text.Contains([gibberishOrNot], ".."))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Or you can add a Function to your model and try to run some Regex expresion:

```
Input Parameters: 
x : String to be searched
y:  search regex
z:  replacement regex
    = (x,y,z)=>
    let 
       Source = Web.Page(
                         "<script>var x="&"'"&x&"'"&";var z="&"'"&z&
                         "'"&";var y=new RegExp('"&y&"','g');
                         var b=x.replace(y,z);document.write(b);</script>")
                         [Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}
    in 
       Source
```

Comment: Thank you for the details example. I would like to filter those gibberish text from that column and get all the meaningful text. How can I achieve this creating a custom column?

Comment: Can you show an example of a conditional column for the above?

Comment: Can you please explain in steps how to use the function? There are hundreds of thousands of gibberish text and I can't even use the conditional column to replace all those with white spaces or blanks because it will take me days.